# Azure Cloud Messaging - Message Processor application gets Exception

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, messaging

I am trying a Cloud application using Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IOT Core.
I have already completed a Universal App which collects data and messages it to the cloud, which is functional.
Next, I try to write a little Application to receive these messages from Azure using the Message Bus.

I have registered my device in Azure (trial version) and got some connection strings and Ids. I use this same connection string to connect to the event message service:

```
string IotHubUri = "HostName=<My>Hub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=<MyRaspiPC>;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=<The primary key>"
string iotHubD2cEndpoint = "messages/events";
EventHubClient client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
                IotHubUri, 
                iotHubD2cEndpoint);
```

The IotHubUri string originally had no "SharedAccessKeyName" in it, I filled it in after getting an exception telling me that there is missing information.
With this KeyName provided, I get another Exception

> Hostname could not be parsed

Since I am using the same pattern as I have found in all books and other information I found on the Internet, I am simply stunned and have no idea how to go on.